# border-image inside element (inset)

Tags: html, css

I have a png file (1603px x 75px) that I would like to use as a border on a section. But I would like it to appear inside (inset) instead of outside. But I cannot figure out how to make the border-image go inside (inset) of exactly the image height, without deforming the vertical dimension of the image.

html:

```
    <section class="intro viewportheight_min" id="intro">
```

css :

```
body, html, .container, section {
  height: 100%;
}
/*.container{margin:0 auto;}*/
section {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
section.intro {
/*  border-color:#06b4c8;*/
/*  border-style:solid;*/
/*  border-width:0 0 75px 0;*/
/*  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;*/
    padding-top: 1%;
    border-style: solid; 
    border-width: 0px 0px 75px 0px;
    -moz-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 stretch; 
    -o-border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 75 stretch; 
    border-image: url(../img/vague.png) 0 0 70 fill stretch; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` property to `section.intro` rule:

```
section.intro {
    ...
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VL5Gw/